# If column 2 is empty, then assign column 4's value to column 2 and column 5's value to column 3

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file

```
Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4 Field5
a1     a2     a3     a4     a5
b1                   b4     b5
c1     c2     c3     c4     c5
d1                   d4     d5
e1                   e4     e5
```

I would like to copy Field 4's value to Field 2 and Field 5's value to Field 3 if Field 2 is empty.

So the expected outcome should be

```
Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4 Field5
a1     a2     a3     a4     a5
b1     b4     b5     b4     b5
c1     c2     c3     c4     c5
d1     d4     d5     d4     d5
e1     e4     e5     e4     e5
```

What I have currently is this

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {
   for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
      if ($2=="") {$2=$7}
  print
   }
}' File > FileA
```

But it doesn't work at all.... Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

edit1:
both input and output file are comma separated, so the raw data will be something like 
input file

```
a1,a2,a3,a4,a5
b1,,,b4,b5
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
d1,,,d4,d5
e1,,,e4,e5
```

Output file

```
a1,a2,a3,a4,a5
b1,b4,b5,b4,b5
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
d1,d4,d5,d4,d5
e1,e4,e5,e4,e5
```

Comment: because `awk` doesn't handle empty fields. there's no fields there, just fixed formatting. So some lines have only 3 fields and some have 5. could be done in awk but not with natural awk field parsing.

Comment: Hi Jean-Francois, so what could I do to improve the code? use sed? could you give me a hint so I can improve it ? Thanks

Comment: You need to tell more about input data formatting? Are there always 3 spaces between fields OR variable # of spaces or these are tab separated?

Comment: @anubhava they are comma separated. just edited in the question

Comment: is it the output or the input which is comma separated? so the input file you're showing has nothing to do with the actual file?

Comment: @KyleGong if input file is comma separated, your sample input needs to reflect that.. also, it could prove to be simple solution if your lines with empty fields look like `b1,,,b4,b5`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $2=="" {$2=$4; $3=$5}1' file
```

Input from file:

```
a1,a2,a3,a4,a5
b1,,,b4,b5
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
d1,,,d4,d5
e1,,,e4,e5
```

Output to stdout:

```
a1,a2,a3,a4,a5  
b1,b4,b5,b4,b5
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
d1,d4,d5,d4,d5
e1,e4,e5,e4,e5
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/?ref=binfind.com/web)

Comment: perhaps move `FS=OFS=","` to `BEGIN` block, otherwise first line won't be converted.

Comment: nitpicking: semicolon not required after the statement block.

Comment: @karakfa: Thank you. I've updated my answer. I'm an awk newbie.

Answer (score 0):

For the simple comma sepator:

```
awk -F\, '$2==""{$2=$4;$3=$5}1' OFS="," File
```

Gives:

```
a1,a2,a3,a4,a5
b1,b4,b5,b4,b5
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
d1,d4,d5,d4,d5
e1,e4,e5,e4,e5
```

**But the *original* question was** about having *fixed-width* fields like these:

```
Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4 Field5
a1     a2     a3     a4     a5
b1                   b4     b5
c1     c2     c3     c4     c5
d1                   d4     d5
e1                   e4     e5
```

Using `gawk`:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="7 7 7 7 7"}
      $2 ~ /^ *$/{$2=$4;$3=$5}
      {split(sprintf($0),a)}{print a[1]"\t"a[2]"\t"a[3]"\t"a[4]"\t"a[5]}' File
```

**Result**

```
Field1  Field2  Field3  Field4  Field5
a1      a2      a3      a4      a5
b1      b4      b5      b4      b5
c1      c2      c3      c4      c5
d1      d4      d5      d4      d5
e1      e4      e5      e4      e5
```

> **FIELDWIDTHS** A space-separated list of columns that tells gawk **how to
>   split input with fixed columnar boundaries**.

Check the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html).

Comment: `!$2` is a success is `$2==0`.

Comment: from the docs:  *In awk, any nonzero numeric value or any nonempty string value is true* , so `!$2` equals to `$2==""` or `$2==0`

Comment: Yes it is. And if there is a zero in `$2` it will be overwritten. OP only mentioned overwriting empties.

Comment: I guess no zeros are coming.. updated the answer anyway. Thanks